# Load windows phone webbrowser in a thread

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Could someone give me an example how to load a local html page in webbrowser control in a thread. The thread should finish execution when script_notify gets called after the browser loads completely and its associated javascript notifies the c# code from its onLoad.  I was also thing about using BackGroundWorker for the same but couldn't think of a way for the above mentioned scenario. Thank in advance.

Comment: Don't know if you can do this. I think this control will work only when visible in the app so it must be in the main thread.

Comment: Actually, i am developing a book reader for loading local language. And the time it takes for the browser to load a render is  lot. So i am using 3 browsers. i.e current, prev and next. any point of time,  only one browser is visible and other 2 are loaded.  The problem i am facing is that when the previous browser is loaded, i have to scroll to the last chapter. And in this case the browser seems to behave stangely. It doesn't do a proper scroll to and shows the first page(No scroll to the end). So i thought, loading that in a thread may help. Any other inputs will be helpful.